# Calculate the distance between fitted hyperplane and points

Tags: python, linear-algebra, svd

I'm trying to find the distance between a fitted hyperplane and five points. Most of the responses I've read use SVM, but I'm not trying to do a classification problem. I know there are probably multiple ways to do this in Python, but I'm a little stumped.

As an example here are my points:

```
[[ 163.3828172   169.65537306  144.69201418]
 [-212.50951396 -167.06555958   56.69388025]
 [-164.65129832 -163.42420063 -149.97008725]
 [  41.8704004    52.2538316    14.0683657 ]
 [-128.38386078 -102.76840542 -303.4960438 ]]
```

To find the equation of a fitted plane I use SVD to compute the coefficients ax + by + cz - b = 0.

```
def fit_plane(points):
    assert points.shape[1] == 3
    centroid = points.mean(axis=0)
    x = points - centroid[None, :]
    U, S, Vt = np.linalg.svd(x.T @ x)
    #normal vector of best fitting plane is the left
    #singular vector corresponding to the least singular value
    normal = U[:, -1]
    #calculate the distance from origin
    origin_distance = normal @ centroid
    return np.hstack([normal, -origin_distance])

fit_plane(X)
```

Giving the equation:

-0.67449074x +  0.73767288y  -0.03001614z -10.75632119 = 0

Now how do I calculate the distance between the points and the hyperplane? The answer I've seen used in conjunction with SVMs is d = |w^Tx +b|/||w||, but I don't know how to go from the equation I have already.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the distance between an equation π and a point P by dropping a perpendicular N from P to π and get the point A where N and π intersect. The distance you are looking for is the distance between A and P.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ackpvEKAYBg) video explains the math of finding A (although it is about finding the reflection, finding A is part of it).